# Hard drive activity every few seconds

Tags: printing, kubuntu, drive

My hard drive is being written to every few seconds, even with no applications running.
The last lines of dmesg shows the following;

```
[19795.860804] type=1400 audit(1411730528.506:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19814.250196] type=1400 audit(1411730546.886:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19814.384451] type=1400 audit(1411730547.022:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6729 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19819.127018] type=1400 audit(1411730551.762:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19819.252497] type=1400 audit(1411730551.886:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6732 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19822.307068] type=1400 audit(1411730554.942:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19822.431494] type=1400 audit(1411730555.066:87): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6735 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19834.097679] type=1400 audit(1411730566.726:88): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19834.224646] type=1400 audit(1411730566.854:89): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6737 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19843.486725] type=1400 audit(1411730576.110:90): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19843.620036] type=1400 audit(1411730576.242:91): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6739 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19845.886539] type=1400 audit(1411730578.510:92): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19846.017403] type=1400 audit(1411730578.638:93): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6741 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19849.911819] type=1400 audit(1411730582.534:94): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19850.034901] type=1400 audit(1411730582.654:95): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6745 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19852.650567] type=1400 audit(1411730585.270:96): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19852.782287] type=1400 audit(1411730585.402:97): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6747 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19868.192415] type=1400 audit(1411730600.806:98): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19868.317112] type=1400 audit(1411730600.930:99): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6775 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19874.845901] type=1400 audit(1411730607.454:100): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19874.978835] type=1400 audit(1411730607.586:101): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6779 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19875.521499] type=1400 audit(1411730608.130:102): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19875.521510] type=1400 audit(1411730608.130:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19875.521516] type=1400 audit(1411730608.130:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19875.521522] type=1400 audit(1411730608.130:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19875.521528] type=1400 audit(1411730608.130:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19875.521533] type=1400 audit(1411730608.130:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19911.194277] type=1400 audit(1411730643.786:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19911.325788] type=1400 audit(1411730643.918:109): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6810 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19911.879630] type=1400 audit(1411730644.470:110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19911.879640] type=1400 audit(1411730644.470:111): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19911.879647] type=1400 audit(1411730644.470:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19928.952673] type=1400 audit(1411730661.538:113): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19929.082148] type=1400 audit(1411730661.666:114): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6827 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[19929.703299] type=1400 audit(1411730662.286:115): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19929.703305] type=1400 audit(1411730662.286:116): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19929.703308] type=1400 audit(1411730662.286:117): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19929.703311] type=1400 audit(1411730662.286:118): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[19929.703314] type=1400 audit(1411730662.286:119): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[20005.090657] type=1400 audit(1411730737.638:120): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20005.212890] type=1400 audit(1411730737.762:121): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6844 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20014.429700] type=1400 audit(1411730746.974:122): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20014.553722] type=1400 audit(1411730747.098:123): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6848 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20019.682823] type=1400 audit(1411730752.226:124): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20019.813025] type=1400 audit(1411730752.354:125): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6850 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20019.846056] type=1400 audit(1411730752.386:126): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20019.974919] type=1400 audit(1411730752.518:127): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6852 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20030.448888] type=1400 audit(1411730762.986:128): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20030.575876] type=1400 audit(1411730763.114:129): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/home/.ecryptfs/andrew/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase" pid=6855 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[20502.974303] type=1400 audit(1411731235.294:130): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[20502.974310] type=1400 audit(1411731235.294:131): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[20502.974313] type=1400 audit(1411731235.294:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[20502.974316] type=1400 audit(1411731235.294:133): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2208 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
```

I re-installed cups and the PDF printer, but with no difference.
I removed the "cups" package, no difference.
I removed "cups-common", no difference.
I removed "cups-server-common", no difference.
I removed "cups-browsed", no difference.
I removed "cups-daemon", no difference.

Has anybody got any ideas I can try ?

Comment: Could you edit your post with the output of `sudo iotop -obtqqq` (after vetting it for sensitive information, of course)? That should give you an overview of all disk access.

Answer (score 0):

You sure no services are running ?

- No Application/Service running ?
- No log is being written ?
- you are not receiving any type of request from any end ?
- you sure no update service updating its cache ?

Comment: How do I tell ?

Comment: Bro , You cant say means how can we help. We have to all processes that are running and we have to see remote services are on/off. with out proper information we cant help you because its your PC/